# YAML Configuration File Parsing Error in CircleCI

Tags: node.js, github, yaml, circleci

I've been trying out CircleCI on my Github repository, but its had some issues in its configuration file. I looked at the template for a Node.js pipeline and designed my own test from it. All it's supposed to do is install Node.js, check its version, and install the latest npm package. After committing the file, CircleCI told me that my build had failed. When I  looked into the logs, I noticed that the YAML configuration file itself was not parsed correctly. I could not find any helpful information by digging around on Google, and making some basic adjustments to my code structuring didn't seem to help either.

Here's my Config file:

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:12.15.0

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
     - checkout
  - run:
          name: "Update files"
          command: |
            curl -sSL "https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.15.0/node-v12.15.0.tar.gz"
            npm @latest -g
  - run:
        name: "Check current version of Node.js"
        command: node -v
```

Here's the log file:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# Unable to parse YAML
# while parsing a block mapping
#  in 'string', line 7, column 3:
#       build:
#       ^
# expected <block end>, but found '-'
#  in 'string', line 21, column 3:
#       - run:
#       ^
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yaml` is very strict about indentation/number of spaces. In your case, problem is with indentation of steps

```
version: 2.0
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:12.15.0

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
            name: "Update files"
            command: |
              curl -sSL "https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.15.0/node-v12.15.0.tar.gz"
              npm @latest -g
      - run:
            name: "Check current version of Node.js"
            command: node -v
```

Comment: Not about less or more, we need to follow same indentation for a particular block. Better use `yaml` plugin support in your IDE or editor, if you're using one